# How to catch exact sql error in php pdo statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to pdo as I am just moving into it from the traditional method of doing queries. Below is what I have wrote and it works. My concern now is that if there any error in any of the query either the select,insert or update they are all capture by that one catch but then I cant pin point exactly to the error. So will multiple try and catch be the right direction ?

```
try {
      $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.dbDatabase.';host='.dbHost;
    $link = new PDO($dsn, dbUser, dbPassword );
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 } catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
$link->beginTransaction();
$rollBackStatus="False";
try
{ 
      $selectQuery1 ="Select ......";

    $selectQueryResult1 = $link->prepare($selectQuery1);
    $selectQueryResult1->bindParam(':uname', $userName);
    $selectQueryResult1->execute();
    $n1=$selectQueryResult1->rowCount();
    //echo "TEST : ".$n1;
    if($n1==1)
    {
        $row1 = $selectQueryResult1->fetch();
        $userID=$row1['userID'];

                if($row1['up']==$up){

            $insertQuery1 ="Insert .......... ".                                     
              $insertQueryResult1 = $link->prepare($insertQuery1);
                $insertQueryResult1->bindParam(':uID', $userID);
                $insertQueryResult1->bindParam(':uIP', $userIP);
                if($insertQueryResult1->execute()){


                }
                else{
                    $rollBackStatus="True";
                    $link->rollback();
                }
                $updateQuery1 ="Update ........ ";
                    $updateQueryResult1 = $link->prepare($updateQuery1);
                $updateQueryResult1->bindParam(':uID', $userID);
                if($updateQueryResult1->execute()){


                }
                else{
                    $rollBackStatus="True";
                    $link->rollback();
                }   
        }           

}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
    $rollBackStatus="True";
    die("Error in selectQuery1 :" . $pe->getMessage());
    $link->rollback();
}
if($rollBackStatus=="False"){
    $link->commit();
    $link=null;
    if($headerSent!="")
    {
        header($headerSent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even a simple search like 'PDO error' would give you [this result](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Comment: @GolezTrol That's too easy!

Comment: @GolezTrol I tried that in my if else of the execute but it didnt seem to produce the error but it comes straight die("Error in selectQuery1 :" . $pe->getMessage());

Comment: Have you read the page? It says: *"`PDO::errorInfo()` only retrieves error information for operations performed directly on the database handle. If you create a PDOStatement object through `PDO::prepare()` or `PDO::query()` and invoke an error on the statement handle, `PDO::errorInfo()` will not reflect the error from the statement handle. You must call `PDOStatement::errorInfo()` to return the error information for an operation performed on a particular statement handle."* The page only has a couple of lines of text. That quote is about half of it. A little bit of effort would be nice.

Comment: So how will PDOStatement::errorInfo() be useful in my case ?

Comment: Ah, I can see the confusion there if you haven't used objects in PHP before or at least didn't read much of the documentation. Well, you prepared a statement (the PDO::prepare function returns a statement). PDO::prepare is a somewhat awkward notation, since it looks like a static call, but you actually call the prepare method on a PDO *instance*, which is what you do in your code as well. The statement you get back is in your `updateQueryResult1` variable, so you can call `$updateQueryResult1->errorInfo()` to get the information you need.

Comment: Well I agree I am new to this pdo not too sure about it but been googling and tested it works. Yes I can call $updateQueryResult1->errorInfo() to retrieve the errorInfo so what is your advice if there any error ? Can I do and if else to to rollback it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check any error after execute  query with following method.

```
$selectQueryResult1->execute();
$arr = $selectQueryResult1->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: if I put die($arr) is that fine or wrong because I am doing transacton base ? So if there is any error I want the whole thing to fail how to modify your suggestion?

Comment: If you use die($arr); then it will exit from that line. it will not execute statement which are written after die(); statement.

Comment: In a transaction environment where I want to rollback what can I improve on my codes. Can I use $arr = $selectQueryResult1->errorInfo(); to check if there is any error ? Is this similar to check for error on my query if($insertQueryResult1->execute()){ ?

Comment: yes you should use it like that if($insertQueryResult1->execute()){ and if error occurs current transaction will not be executed.

Comment: So if I user this method if($insertQueryResult1->execute()){ like how I have now I think in the else I can put this rite $arr = $selectQueryResult1->errorInfo();
print_r($arr); and also rollback? Then must I also set the rollback variable so that the end it can be check to be rollback or commit?

Comment: in the else part if you get $arr = $selectQueryResult1->errorInfo();  it means you have error and your query not executed So you dont need to execute rollback command.

Comment: How to check if $arr just for a boolean or integer value? So then when to call the rollback? Is it the catch is sufficient or just dont call it and just decide to commit at the if($rollBackStatus=="False"){?

Comment: you need to use if($insertQueryResult1->execute()) this will return true if success and false on failure.

Comment: Yes sagar I have this if($insertQueryResult1->execute()) so in the else I add this $arr = $selectQueryResult1->errorInfo(); ? any thing else I can do or should I run separate try and catch for each query ?